# Open button (after application re-install by code) does not launch app

Tags: android

I re-install my .apk programmatically by code while it is running and when re-install finishes Open button does not launch the app.It just closes Open Finish window.Then I have to go to menu and launch it clicking there.

Does anyone know anything about this issue?

I guess this would be because the application signature changes or sth like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity name may have changed, and now home screen shortcut probably points to non-existing activity.
Delete the old home-screen shortcut, and place there new one.

Comment: Hmm,I don't have a home screen shortcut indeed I don't create manually either.I re-install exactly same apk file.Maybe it is because menu launcher icon still pointing the removed activity...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have code below for your main activity in your Manifest:

   ```
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```
2. Also make sure to close your app when you are reinstalling. You can use this:

   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

   or

   System.exit(0);
3. Finally Add the code below to your onCreate() in your Main Activity :

   if (!isTaskRoot()) {

   ```
               finish();
               return;
           }
   ```

Hope it works :)